# Importing file names from directory to listbox

Tags: vb.net

Looking for some simple code that will import all of the file names from a directory and its subdirectories.

I'm aware they're a couple of similar posts to this, however, couldn't get any of them to work, possibly just being an idiot.

Cheers for any help.

Comment: If what you tried didn't work then you did it wrong. We can't know what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did. This site is not a place where you ask people to do things from scratch for you. It's where you show us what you tried and we help you fix it.

Comment: Sorry lads. First time asking a question on a site like this for help. In future I will include code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this recently - hope it helps you !

```
Dim strFilepath = "c:\store-3"  'Specify path details
Dim directory As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strFilepath)
Dim File2 As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  Dim File1 As System.IO.FileInfo
    For Each File1 In File2
        Dim strLastModified As String
        strLastModified = File1.DirectoryName & "\" + File1.Name & ">Date:" & System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(strFilepath & "\" & File1.Name).ToShortDateString()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(strLastModified)
    Next
```

Don't forget :- Imports system.io and putting a listbox1 on your form. . .

Comment: Cheers mate this solved it. Been using a workaround since I had the problem and this has made my life so much easier. Cheers!